# Fill a list with 10 random numbers, then chose 5 of them randomly

Tags: python, loops, random

I want to generate a list with 10 random floats using a loop. Afterwards I want to print 5 of these randomly.

I have this loop:

```
    import random
    for i in range(5):
        print(float(random.randint(1,10)
```

this gives me an output of 5 random numbers between 1-10. But is the result really random floats?

With this, I didn't really fill a list with 10 random floats did I?

```
    for a in range(1,11,1):
        print(a)
```

would this be better? As I understood, random.sample creates a list automatically. Is that true?

```
    import random
    a = random.sample(range(1,11),10)
    print(a)
```

there the output would be e.g.:
[1, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 5, 8, 4, 2]

but then it would give me just 1-10 back in a random order.

So I could change range to range(1,1000),10)

Then it would create a list with 10 random numbers only within 1 to 1000.

Is there a solution to this? I am just curious, bc if its infinite then I likely get a 10 digit number which is way too long.

If I want to choose 5 random numbers from the randomly filled list I tried to use this code:

```
    import random
    a = random.sample(range(1,1000),10)

    for a in range(5):
        print(a)
```

but this gives me only that:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I know it has to be something about the range(5) but I assume that the loop doesn't choose the numbers from the list I created, am I right?

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://devinsimplewords.com/python-random-number/

Comment: You are printing the indices, not the values. Either use `for x in a: print(x)`, or use `for i in range(5): print(a[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.sample` returns unique random elements - i.e. if you sample 10 elements from a list of 10 elements - all elements are guaranteed to be there

From the docs `help(random.sample)` -

> sample(population, k) method of random.Random instance
> Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence or set.

To sample with repetition, you can use the `choices` function -

From the docs - `help(random.choices)`

> choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1) method of
> random.Random instance
> Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement.

For example,

```py
b = random.choices(range(1, 11), k=10)
print(b)
# [1, 10, 9, 8, 6, 1, 6, 4, 9, 3]
```